# How can I make a grid between some lines that, given a value, the grid moves between the lines?

Tags: matplotlib

I have been trying with some matplotlib functions, but it does not come out, I tried with the one of plt.hlines and plt.vlines to put them but it did not work for me.
This is my code, I need my grid to move between the blue lines.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Dec 29 16:33:11 2020

@author: 146282
"""
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
V=float(input("Introduzca la velocidad en terminos de c:"))
if(V>=0 and V<1):



    x=np.arange(0,10,.1)
    y=np.arange(0,10,.1)
    x2=np.arange(-10,10,1)
    y2=np.arange(-10,10,1)



    plt.axvline(x=0,ymin=0, ymax=10, color='k')
    plt.axhline(y=0, xmin=0.,xmax=10, color='k')
    plt.axvline(x=1,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet',label='Malla S')
    plt.axhline(y=1, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=2,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=2, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=3,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=3, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=4,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=4, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=5,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=6,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=6, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=7,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=7, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axvline(x=8,ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet')
    plt.axhline(y=8, xmin=0.5,xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet')

    x5=np.array([0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10])
    x6=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    fx=abs(x)
    plt.plot(x5,x6,color='chocolate',label='Cono de Luz')
    plt.xlim(-10,10)
    plt.plot(x6,x5,color='chocolate')
    plt.plot(-x5,x6,color='chocolate')
    #plt.plot(-x2,-x)
    plt.plot(-x6,x5,color='chocolate')
    plt.ylim(-10,10)

    #HIPER
    xh=np.linspace(-10,10,500)
    yh=np.linspace(-10,10,500)
    v=1-V 
    def axes():
        plt.axhline(0,alpha=.1)
        plt.axvline(0,alpha=.1)
    b=1
    a=1
    xh,yh=np.meshgrid(xh,yh)
    axes()
    plt.contour(xh,yh,((xh**2/a**2)-(yh**2/b**2)),[1],colors='orchid')
    plt.contour(xh,yh,(-(xh**2/a**2)+(yh**2/b**2)),[1],colors='orchid')
    plt.plot(x,y,color='aqua',label='Velocidad de la luz')
    #EJES_PRIMOS
    c=1
    xt=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    ct=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    xprima=(xt+v*ct)/(np.sqrt(1-v**2/c**2))
    ctprima=(ct-(v/c**2)*xt)/np.sqrt(1-v**2/c**2)
    plt.plot(xprima,'b')
    plt.plot(ctprima,'b')
    # plt.vlines(ctprima, xprima,xprima, colors='k', linestyles='solid')
    #plt.hlines(ctprima,9)
    #plt.vlines(xprima,)
    #plot(ctprima)

    plt.title("MINKOWSKI DIAGRAM")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
else:
    print('Error')
```

Will there be some function that makes it fast, or it will be necessary to do it by applying other methods, I also had in mind to do it by means of vectors, or by means of a line each line of the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a polygon by combining the curves from `xprima` and `ctprima`. To create a closed polygon, one of the curves need to be reversed. The x-values for `xprima` are `xt`, while for `ctprima` they are `ct`. So, the x-values for the polygon are `np.append(xt, ct[::-1])` and similar for the y-values. To create the polygon, `Polygon` needs the xy positions as an `Nx2` array which can be created using `np.vstack` and transposing (`.T`).

This polygon can be either used to clip the gridlines, or could just be used to be "hatched" without the need for the gridlines.

The gridlines can be created via for-loops: `[plt.axvline(x=i, ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9) for i in range(1, 9)]`. If the result is stored in an array, it can be used to call `.set_clip_path(polygon)` on them.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

# V = float(input("Introduzca la velocidad en terminos de c (0 <= V < 1):"))
V = 0.2
if (0 <= V < 1):
    plt.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=10, color='k')
    plt.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=10, color='k')
    plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
    plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

    grid_lines = [plt.axvline(x=i, ymin=0.5, ymax=0.9, color='darkviolet') for i in range(1, 9)]
    grid_lines += [plt.axhline(y=i, xmin=0.5, xmax=0.9, color='darkviolet') for i in range(1, 9)]
    grid_lines[0].set_label('Malla S')

    plt.plot([-10, 10], [-10, 10], color='chocolate', label='Cono de Luz')
    plt.plot([-10, 10], [10, -10], color='chocolate')

    v = 1 - V
    b = 1
    a = 1
    # HIPER
    xh, yh = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 500), np.linspace(-10, 10, 500))

    plt.contour(xh, yh, xh ** 2 / a ** 2 - yh ** 2 / b ** 2, [-1, 1], colors='orchid')
    plt.plot([0, 10], [0, 10], color='aqua', label='Velocidad de la luz')
    # EJES_PRIMOS
    c = 1
    xt = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    ct = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    xprima = (xt + v * ct) / (np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2))
    ctprima = (ct - (v / c ** 2) * xt) / np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2)
    plt.plot(xt, xprima, 'b')
    plt.plot(ct, ctprima, 'b')

    poly = Polygon(np.vstack([np.append(xt, ct[::-1]), np.append(xprima, ctprima[::-1])]).T, transform=plt.gca().transData)
    for line in grid_lines:
        line.set_clip_path(poly)

    plt.ylim(-10, 10)
    plt.xlim(-10, 10)
    plt.title("MINKOWSKI DIAGRAM")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
else:
    print('Error')
```

[image: resulting plot]

The gridlines can also be created more automatically via ["hatching"](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch). For horizontal and vertical line, the hatch pattern would be '+'. Other possible patterns are 'x', '/', 'o', '*', ... . Repeating the symbol in the string (e.g. '+++' puts the lines closer together.

```py
plt.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=10, color='k')
plt.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=10, color='k')
plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

plt.plot([-10, 10], [-10, 10], color='chocolate', label='Cono de Luz')
plt.plot([-10, 10], [10, -10], color='chocolate')

v = 1 - V
b = 1
a = 1
# HIPER
xh, yh = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 500), np.linspace(-10, 10, 500))
plt.contour(xh, yh, xh ** 2 / a ** 2 - yh ** 2 / b ** 2, [-1, 1], colors='orchid')
plt.plot([0, 10], [0, 10], color='aqua', label='Velocidad de la luz')
# EJES_PRIMOS
c = 1
xt = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
ct = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
xprima = (xt + v * ct) / (np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2))
ctprima = (ct - (v / c ** 2) * xt) / np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2)
plt.plot(xt, xprima, 'b')
plt.plot(ct, ctprima, 'b')

poly = Polygon(np.vstack([np.append(xt, ct[::-1]), np.append(xprima, ctprima[::-1])]).T,
               facecolor='none', lw=0, edgecolor='darkviolet', hatch='+', label='Malla S',
               transform=plt.gca().transData)
plt.gca().add_patch(poly)

plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.title("MINKOWSKI DIAGRAM")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

PS: To have the gridlines parallel to the blue lines, they can be generated as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

V = 0.2
plt.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=10, color='k')
plt.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=10, color='k')
plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

plt.plot([-10, 10], [-10, 10], color='chocolate', label='Cono de Luz')
plt.plot([-10, 10], [10, -10], color='chocolate')

v = 1 - V
b = 1
a = 1

xh, yh = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 500), np.linspace(-10, 10, 500))
plt.contour(xh, yh, xh ** 2 / a ** 2 - yh ** 2 / b ** 2, [-1, 1], colors='orchid')
plt.plot([0, 10], [0, 10], color='aqua', label='Velocidad de la luz')

c = 1
xt = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
ct = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
xprima = (xt + v * ct) / (np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2))
ctprima = (ct - (v / c ** 2) * xt) / np.sqrt(1 - v ** 2 / c ** 2)
plt.plot(xt, xprima, 'b')
plt.plot(ct, ctprima, 'b')

grid_lines = [plt.plot(xt + cti, xprima + ctprima_i, c='darkviolet')[0] for cti, ctprima_i in zip(ct[1:], ctprima[1:])]
grid_lines += [plt.plot(ct + xti, ctprima + xprima_i, c='darkviolet')[0] for xti, xprima_i in zip(xt[1:], xprima[1:])]

grid_lines[0].set_label('Malla S')

plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.title("MINKOWSKI DIAGRAM")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: grid lines parallel with the blue lines]

Comment: Thank u so much, it was so close what i expected, but the purple lines have to be parallel to the axes, of the two blue axes, not straight as they come out, something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/13o6t6kRUIebYF8GuUvR-ECAVBZCpstJD/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to draw the gridlines parallel to the blue lines.